# UIButton contentVerticalAlignment doesn't center button image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created a UIButton programmatically and set its image, but the image just won't center vertically, it's always rendered at the bottom of the button.

Here is my code:

```
CGFloat logoutButtonSize = self.profileItem.detailView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat logoutButtonX = self.profileItem.detailView.frame.size.width - logoutButtonSize - 8;
CGRect logoutButtonFrame = CGRectMake(logoutButtonX, 0, logoutButtonSize, logoutButtonSize);
UIButton *logoutButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:logoutButtonFrame];
[logoutButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
logoutButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
logoutButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[logoutButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(confirmLogout)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
logoutButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
logoutButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
logoutButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

After setting a distinct background color for the imageView of the button I can see that it's still aligned to the bottom:

(blue = button, red = image view)

[image]

Why is it not working?

Comment: check my answer, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your posted image, it looks like the Button itself is being clipped at the bottom, as opposed to the image not being centered vertically.

Your code:

```
CGRect logoutButtonFrame = CGRectMake(logoutButtonX, 0, logoutButtonSize, logoutButtonSize);
```

says the Button (blue rectangle) should be square. Yet in the image you posted, the blue rectangle is `120 x 88`.

The bottom portion of your button is not being displayed, so it *looks* like your image is not centered.

By the way, you shouldn't need much of the code you are using:

```
    // define the frame size
    CGFloat logoutButtonSize = self.profileItem.detailView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat logoutButtonX = self.profileItem.detailView.frame.size.width - logoutButtonSize - 8;
    CGRect logoutButtonFrame = CGRectMake(logoutButtonX, 0, logoutButtonSize, logoutButtonSize);

    // instantiate the UIButton
    UIButton *logoutButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:logoutButtonFrame];

    // set the image
    [logoutButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // add the button action target
    [logoutButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(confirmLogout)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // set the resizing mask properties
    logoutButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // shouldn't need any of the following
    //logoutButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    //logoutButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    //logoutButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    //logoutButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: You are right, the button was clipped at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Point 1

AFAIK, `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` & `contentHorizontalAlignment` is for text alignment and not for image....

### Point 2

`UIButton *logoutButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:logoutButtonFrame];` will create basic button (like < iOS 6) opposed to Custom button. Below is how you should have button programmatically.

```
UIButton * logoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[logoutButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(confirmLogout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[logoutButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(logoutButtonX, 0, logoutButtonSize, logoutButtonSize);
[self.view addSubview: logoutButton];
```

Now for image to adjust,

```
continueButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

You are done...

### And last

Your code is not working because your UIButton is not Custom button.

Comment: Thanks for the custom button tip, I didn't know that it can affect something. However, I found that the image wasn't aligned because the button was cut off at the bottom. Thanks again!

Comment: No interface for UIButton declares the selector setBackgroundImage:forControlEvents:

The closest to that is setBackgroundImage:forState:

You probably meant [logoutButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];